# Rare interesting primes such as Wolstenholme and Wieferich primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, soft-question, conjectures

Take a look at the following two examples of "rare interesting primes";

Wolstenholme prime is a special prime number related to a stronger version of  Wolstenholme's theorem. They have connections to Fermat's last theorem. The only known such primes are $16843$ and $2124679$, but it is believed (conjectured) that there are infinitely many. The corresponding OEIS sequence is A088164.

> **Definition.** A Wolstenholme prime is a prime number $p > 7$ that satisfies the congruence
>
> $$\left(\begin{array}{l}2 p-1 \\p-1\end{array}\right) \equiv 1 \quad\left(\bmod p^{4}\right).$$

Wieferich prime is a prime number related to a stronger version of Fermat's little theorem. They appear in works pertaining to Fermat's last theorem. The only known such primes are $1093$ and $3511$, but it is believed that there are infinitely many. The corresponding OEIS sequence is A001220.

> **Definition.** Wieferich prime is a prime number $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $2^{p − 1} − 1$.

---

I was wondering,

> **Question.** Are there any other types of "rare interesting primes"? I.e. primes related to known results in number theory and have been studied (there exist compelling references, i.e. such primes are "interesting"), but do not have many examples (are "rare").

For non-example, Twin primes are "interesting", but are not "rare" since one can easily list say [$10^4$ examples](https://oeis.org/A001097/b001097.txt).

For example, Fermat primes are "interesting" and are "rare". Only known are $3, 5, 17, 257, 65537$. It is conjectured that these are the only terms (unlike the Wolstenholme and Wieferich primes).

Another example may be of Mersenne Primes. We can list [around $50$ examples at the moment](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/), where the largest example holds the current record for the largest prime.

Are there any other examples?

Comment: [Wilson primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime), $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p^2}$. Only three found so far, $5,13,563$.

Comment: Wall sun sun primes , infinite many expected although none known.

Comment: Of great interest are surely also the factorial and the primorial primes.

Comment: @Peter Ah yes, factorial and primorial primes. Now I'm wondering if one of the tags on the question should be replaced with `big-list`.

Comment: Rep-unit primes also come in my mind. Only a "handful" are known.

Comment: I would remove soft-question

Comment: Do you also count the "ec-primes" ? (I guess you know what I mean) ?

Comment: I suggest to post an answer as "community" and list the examples you know, and everyone can add examples by editing.

Comment: @Peter Should I post a single community answer that will be edited by people? Or should the question be a big-list tag and many individual answers (In that case, would you suggest everything be community)? I'm never sure when things are considered appropriate `big-list`'s or "community", or not.

Comment: I have no experience with that either. I think, one answer would be best (other people can add answers anyway if they want.

Comment: @Peter I've added a community answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Below is the list of suggestions from the community. Feel free to edit or expand this answer.*

*The "Expected" column represents the **conjectured** number of such primes*.

$$\begin{array}{lllcc}
\text{Name} & \text{Definition, }p\in\mathbb P & \text{Known examples} & \text{No.} & \text{Expected}\\
\hline
\text{ Wolstenholme } 
& \left\{p\gt 7 : \left(\begin{array}{l}2 p-1 \\p-1\end{array}\right) \equiv 1 \left(\bmod p^{4}\right) \right\}
& \{16843, 2124679\}
& 2
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Wieferich } 
& \left\{ p : p^2 \mid 2^{p − 1} − 1 \right\}
& \{1093, 3511\}
& 2
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Wilson } 
& \left\{ p : p^2 \mid (p − 1)! + 1 \right\}
& \{5,13,563\}
& 3
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Wall-Sun-Sun } 
& \left\{ p : p^2 \mid F_{\pi(p)} \right\}^{[1]}
& \{\}
& 0
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Woodall } 
& \left\{ p : p = 2^nn-1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \text{oeis.org/A002234}
& 34
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Cullen } 
& \left\{ p : p = 2^nn+1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \text{oeis.org/A005849}
& 16
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Mersenne } 
& \left\{ p : p = 2^n-1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \text{mersenne.org/primes}
& 51
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Fermat } 
& \left\{ p : p = 2^{2^n}+1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \{3, 5, 17, 257, 65537\}
& 5
& 5
\\
\text{ Factorial } 
& \left\{ p : p = n!\pm1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \begin{array}{}\text{oeis.org/A002981},\\\text{oeis.org/A002982}\end{array}
& 49
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Primorial } 
& \left\{ p : p = p_n\#\pm1,n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \begin{array}{}\text{oeis.org/A006794},\\\text{oeis.org/A005234}\end{array}
& 42
& \text{infinite}
\\
\text{ Repunit }
& \left\{ p : p = \frac{10^n - 1}{9}, n\in\mathbb N \right\}
& \text{oeis.org/A004023}
& 9
& \text{infinite}
\end{array}$$

---

*Clarifications:*

$[1]$ Wall–Sun–Sun primes - $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers and $\pi(p)$ is Pisano period. - [[wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime#Definition)